# custom UITableViewCell to be used both with NIB and programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

*Disclaimer: I'm new comparably new to iOS development. I'm using ARC for this project*

I have a very simple custom `UITableViewCell`

**UITableViewListRightAlignedCell.h**

```
@interface UITableViewListRightAlignedCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgIcon;

@end
```

**UITableViewListRightAlignedCell.m**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self initalize];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self initalize];
}

-(void) initalize {
    self.lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.lblTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    self.lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONTRobotoRegular size:16];
    self.lblTitle.textColor = RGBColor(0x5D350BFF);  
}
```

This custom cell works fine when I have a cell in my storyboard and I connect `UILabel` to `lblTitle` and an `UIImage` to `imgIcon`.

However, I want to use the same custom cell class somewhere else in the code with a programmatically created `UITableView`. The problem is that the properties `lblTitle` and `imgIcon` are not being set because they are not initialized and I can't initialize them because them because are they are outlets and `weak`.

I need to know what's the correct approach in this case.

Comment: You should stay clear of prefixing your custom class names with UI as this is what Apple uses for standard UIKit classes and could cause conflicts in future iOS versions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708387/objective-c-class-prefixes

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) {

            [self createMyLabel:nil];// create your label here
            // Initialization code
            [self initalize];
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void)awakeFromNib {
        [super awakeFromNib];
        [self initalize];
    }

    -(void) initalize {
        //self.lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.lblTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        self.lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONTRobotoRegular size:16];
        self.lblTitle.textColor = RGBColor(0x5D350BFF);  
    }



    -(void)createMyLabel:(id)sender{

        //Create your label
        UILabel *MyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];

        //Set background color for debugging
        [storeAddress setBackgroundColor: [UIColor blueColor]];

        //set this created label as your lblTitle label
        [self setLblTitle:MyLabel];


        //Add it to the cell's content view
        [[self contentView] addSubview:[self lblTitle]];


        //Then do something with that
        //[self initalize];

        //[MyLabel release]; // For Non ARC

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each table view cell contains contentView. This view is what you see in IB. When you add controls to it in IB (UILabel in your case), you can use them as weak because this contentView already has strong reference to it. So what you need:

```
UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[label setText:@"Test"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
[cell setTitleLabel:label];
```

Comment: I want a custom cell that can be used both with NIB and programmatically. In this case you're adding the label two times.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that when using a Storyboard, only awakeFromNib is called. initWithStyle is called only in the case of a programmatical initialization by another class.

Therefore, you are correct when using this kind of code :

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self initalize];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self initalize];
}

-(void) initalize {
   // initialization code  
}
```

This is exactly what Paul Hegarty shows in the Stanford iOS course. It ensures that whatever the caller, your class is initialized in a consistent way.

So, to answer your question, if you want to use this class programmatically, add this kind of code ONLY in the initWithStyle method (since it's the one being called programmatically) :

```
_lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[self.contentView addSubview:_lblTitle];
```

Same thing for your other property.

Of course, you don't add that to the awakeFromNib method, since your outlets will already be initialized by the storyboard itself.

Regards,
Fred